# Coldfusion 10 cfchart/ZingChart not accepting pie chart detach property

Tags: charts, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, zingchart

I am trying to create a pie chart that expands a pie slice when it is clicked as [shown in this example](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!colorful-pie-chart). 
Below is my ColdFusion code which, according to the ZingChart [docs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/pie-charts/#basic-elements-chart-specific-clicked-slices), allows a detach property to be set to true that should allow this behavior. It does not seem to be working however. The line-style property that I set works but not the detach property. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<cfset plot = {"line-style":"dotted","detach": "true"}>
<cfchart format="html" title="Sales Report"  plot="#plot#">
    <cfchartseries type="pie">
        <cfchartdata item="2012" value="25">
        <cfchartdata item="2013" value="25">
        <cfchartdata item="2014" value="25">
        <cfchartdata item="2015" value="25">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

The `detached` property does not work because the build cfcharts currently uses is not up to date with the build that the `detached` property was added.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Do you know if cfchart at some point will update the build and for now is there any way to manually update the build?

Comment: I'm not sure when they will update the build and don't think I can release any of that information if I did know. There is no way to update the build in cfchart because they map our syntax to their own.

You can use [offsetR](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/pie-charts/#pie-chart-types-exploded-pie-chart) to simulate a `detached` slice.

Comment: Thank you. It looks zingchart is updated in Cf 2016 based on this https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3476873